# How do I add commas to this to make it into a proper list on python?

Tags: python

I want to make this into a proper list by adding commas in-between the values in brackets.

```
[119033] [656516, 34751, 2180, 656495, 66509032, 441462, 24801909, 134694146] [3220] [68313] [104735] [110685] [6432223] [565394] [519872] [] [5320377] [10855848] [11789573] [] [13745740] [101293645] [] [5464156, 94060] [] [] [] [] [6654] [2537]
```

I want the output to look like this

```
[119033], [656516, 34751, 2180, 656495, 66509032, 441462, 24801909, 134694146], [3220],[68313], [104735], [110685], [6432223], [565394], [519872], [], [5320377], [10855848], [11789573], [], [13745740], [101293645], [], [5464156, 94060], [], [], [], [], [6654], [2537]
```

And if possible I would also like to remove the empty brackets.

Comment: Hi. This is not a proper datatype. This has to be a string '[[1] [2]]'. Please clarify.

Comment: do you have the variable names holding each list?

Comment: Just replace `]` with `],`, then remove the last `,`

Comment: I have a list of chemical names I input into Pubchem and this is the chemical ids that were given as output, I do not have any more information.

Comment: Is this in a string?

Comment: Hm, I think they are separated by newline, but the editor did not get it.

Comment: It might actually be a new line because when I do print (type()) I get class 'list'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```py
for x in list_of_data:
  if x == '[]':
    pass
  else:
    print(x)
```

That should at least get rid of the empty brackets.
I don't know what to do, this doesn't look like a normal datatype for Python...

Comment: Where are you adding commas?

Comment: What is `list_of_data`? The original data is not a list.

Comment: It isn't a list I'm trying to make it Into a list by adding commas between ], [ if that's even possible.

Comment: @CelinYounan If this answer doesn't solve your problem, you might want to consider removing the Accepted Answer flag on it. Just click on the checkbox symbol to unaccept it, or click on it for a difference answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the original data is a string, you can just use `str.replace()` to insert the commas.

```
input_str = '[119033] [656516, 34751, 2180, 656495, 66509032, 441462, 24801909, 134694146] [3220] [68313] [104735] [110685] [6432223] [565394] [519872] [] [5320377] [10855848] [11789573] [] [13745740] [101293645] [] [5464156, 94060] [] [] [] [] [6654] [2537]'
output_str = input_str.replace('] [', '], [')
print(output_str)
```

Note that this is still not the format of a proper list, because that needs `[]` around the whole thing. You can then convert that to a list using `ast.literal_eval()`.

```
import ast

proper_list = ast.literal_eval('[' + output_str + ']');
print(proper_list);
```

You can get rid of the empty brackets with a list comprehension.

```
no_empty = [el for el in proper_list if el]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this data was generated a function that returns a list that is repeatedly called (which, for the sake of simplicity, I will just call `list_generator()`), rather than being a string formatted this way, then you could simply do something like this:

```
new_list = []

for i in range(1,10):
  new_list.append(list_generator(i))
```

That is, for each call of list_generator in the iteration of your set, you simply append it to an empty list. If you want to discard empty lists, then just add a check for empty lists prior to appending it.

```
new_list = []

for i in range(1,10):
  list_item = list_generator(i)
  if list_item: 
    new_list.append(list_item)
```

Of course, you'd replace the for `for i in range(1,10)` iteration with whatever iteration you're actually using, as well as replacing `list_generator(i)` with whatever function and parameters are actually being used to generate these values.

Answer (score 0):

I have considered that the given in input is entirely a string. Which means

```
input ="[119033] [656516, 34751, 2180, 656495, 66509032, 441462, 24801909, 134694146] [3220] [68313] [104735] [110685] [6432223] [565394] [519872] [] [5320377] [10855848] [11789573] [] [13745740] [101293645] [] [5464156, 94060] [] [] [] [] [6654] [2537]"
```

Then your problem is purely on string manipulation. I want to notify that I did not want to use Regular expressions in this scenario and I just went on coding using `for` and `if-else`. Using `Regular expressions` might make your code more compact. Nevertheless, I started off by stripping away unwanted white spaces and commas at this point and stored the content in 'temp' by using the following code -

```
temp=[(i.strip("[").strip("]").split()) for i in string.replace(", ",",").split(" ")]

print(temp)
```

The `print(temp)` statement is used for debugging & understanding purposes which you are at liberty to remove as seen fit. Since you did not want any blank lists, I dealt with that query in the following code -

```
RemovedBlankLists=[]

[[RemovedBlankLists.append(j.split(",")) for j in i] for i in temp]

print(RemovedBlankLists)
```

Again the `print(RemovedBlankLists)` statement is used for debugging & understanding purposes which you may remove as seen fit. The above gets rid of blank lists and splits the lists at `,` which will be useful in the next step. The final part of the code is as follows -

```
y=[]
for i in RemovedBlankLists:
    if len(i) < 1:
        [y.append(int(j)) for j in i]
    else:
        temp = [int(j) for j in i]
        y.append(temp)
print(y)
```

The last `print(y)` statement shall produce your desired output. Happy Coding !
Let me know if my assumption is wrong and If I have to consider the input as something else. I would love to code for the alternative too.